# Is it possible to migrate a set of GitLab **runners** from one server to another

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a small server which has a series of 30 or 40 gitlab runners configured on it, to deploy code from a Gitlab server on a different machine, which belongs to the non-profit I volunteer for.

The small server is running out of puff, but there is a different, larger server I could move the runners to, which has plenty of spare capacity.

Is there a way of simply copying the entire gitlab runner configuration from the small server to the other one, or do I have to recreate every one of the 30 or 40 runners on the larger server, then delete the ones from the small server?

I know I have tried copying individual config.toml runners from one server to another in the past, and they haven't worked.

The runners are mostly docker or ssh runners.